# kSoap-2 android nullpointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, soapui, android-ksoap2

I am working with ksoap2 for android and I am sending SOAP requests. I was googling for a whole day and couldn't find solution for my problem. The first problem was with i:type, my service was returning fault for requests with i:type, so I found that this can be fixed using

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);

instead of

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

and that fixed the i:type problem. Now the generated request doesn't contain i:type and if I send it using SOAP UI it works fine, but now I get **NullPointerException**

in this line

httpTransport.call(DEFAULT_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Can anyone help me out with this? If u need my code I can post it. I also tried using different versions of ksoap .jar file and it didn't help.

Comment: Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will need this.

I solved this by setting types explicitly (for each PropertyInfo there is .setType function which receives type class String.class etc.) and use

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

and using that removes i:type from the soap request. Hope it will help someone.